# Ray-Square Intersection where the Ray always lies on the Interior of the Square?

Tags: bounding-boxes, intersection

I recently wrote a quick shader toy for finding the point of intersection of a ray centered within a square--with optimization provided by the Graphics Programming discord: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/mtdyDn

The resulting solution was as follows:

```
For some line x1,y1,x2,y2 and some square centered at x1,y1 with
a length of N, find the long-side of the triangle formed by x1,y1
and x2,y2. Then find scalar of 1/2 of N and the long leg of the
triangle, then project backwards x2,y2 towards x1,y1 by that scalar.
```

However I cannot seem to figure out how to adapt it to rays offset from the center. There's always plenty of material online for Ray and AABB intersection. Is there a faster method specifically for finding the point of intersection of a ray that ALWAYS lies on the interior of some square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some glsl-type code for how we can do this. The trick is to think of the ray as a particle starting at some position and moving at some velocity. Then we can calculate how long it takes the particle to cross a threshold x or y value (the bounds of the square/AABB), and pick the least (positive) value as the time of first impact. From that time, we can produce the point on the ray where the intersection occurs.

```
vec2 rayVsAABB(vec2 position, vec2 direction, vec2 min, vec2 max) {
    // The limiting value is the boundary on the side the ray is pointing
    vec2 limit;
    limit.x = direction.x >= 0 ? max.x : min.x;
    limit.y = direction.y >= 0 ? max.y : min.y;

    // If your box is always a square centered on the origin, this can be
    // limit = sign(direction) * halfWidth;

    // The signed distance we have to travel from the ray start to hit the limit on x, y:
    vec2 fromLimit = limit - position;

    // How long it takes to reach that limit, if "direction" were a particle's velocity
    vec2 timeToLimit = fromLimit / direction;

    // The earliest intersection time gives us the side we hit first
    float t = min(timeToLimit.x, timeToLimit.y);

    // Construct the point on the ray at a "time" t along its length
    // (t is the distance if direction is a unit vector) 
    return position + t * direction;
}
```

Comment: Won't the `fromLimit / direction` produce a divide by zero error?

Comment: In GLSL, no, you'll get positive infinity, which compares correctly in the `min` function to always select the other alternative. It might misbehave if `fromLimit` is *also* zero, in which case the result is `NaN`, but you defined the ray origin to always be in the interior of the square, not on its perimeter. You can detect this case and return the point itself if that's the desired output for that scenario.

Comment: Or you can replace the `min` with the funny looking `timeToLimit.x < timeToLimit.y ? timeToLimit.x : (isnan(timeToLimit.y) ? timeToLimit.x : timeToLimit.y)` — that ensures you get a non-NaN output even if you get a NaN upstream. With this, a ray on the box perimeter parallel to the side it's on will return a hit where it exits the box at a corner, rather than its starting point or any point in between where it's skating — but not *crossing* — the edge.

Comment: I see an attempt to edit new code into this answer. Please post that as its own separate answer.